# title property in vis.js not work?( the data is get by ajax)

Tags: javascript, vis.js

here is the code:

```
nodes.push({
  id: d_id, 
  shape: 'image', 
  image: DIR + '_honeypot.png', 
  title: '<div>类型: '+d_type+'</div>' + '<div>IP: '+d_ip+'</div>' + '<div>状态：'+activity+d_runtime+'</div>', 
  label: d_type});
```

but the event of `hoverNode` is work. like the code:

```
network.on("hoverNode",function () {
        console.log("ok111");
    });
```

if not solved, have mind to using `hoverNode` to replace `title`

Can you help me please?  (sorry my english is not good)

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand from this page http://visjs.org/docs/network/interaction.html# the hover option is defaulted to false. Have you changed it to true?

Comment: `autoResize: true,
            interaction: {
                hover: true,
                zoomView: false
            },`

Comment: I   have  changed it, but it doesn't work...  however,  it running in my locallhost, the data is  simulated by str.

Comment: i have solved it, cause i am not linked the .css file  :)

Comment: I had the same problem, the CSS file I used to include went down. Checked the official [titles example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/html-in-titles.html) and it doesn't need the CSS file. I included their standalone JS file and it works with it. It probably loads it dinamically.